# Mac OS Sierra install failure: The file couldn't be opened

Tags: macos-sierra

While trying to perform a clean installation of MacOS Sierra on a Macbook Pro 2012 (8Gb ram, 250 SSD Crucial Driver and i5 processor) **through the boot install option (cmd + r)** from the web (Internet install, an this is needed as I just installed the new SSD) the operation always gets stuck at 2 minutes before finishing.

Left it the whole night and in the morning saw the message in the image of this post.

Booted in the new AFP2 filesystem format for the drive as required in the Sierra version. Created the partition and erased the disk without any problem.

Seems the installer is fail fast but not very descriptive, any help would be appreciated otherwise that Mac will likely be a deluxe "cup holder" :(

Thanks a million

[sierra boot install failure picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsjx9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself in the end, for anybody stuck on this in the future.

And the only way I found out to do it is to **install the OS that came with the Macbook Pro** (2010 Mountain Lion in my case) and then update but from the installed system rather than the boot repair util.

- Restart the Macbook and right after you hear the sound hold the *option* key until you see the spinning globe icon.
- Input the WiFi credentials to access the repair util (this is the original util that came with your mac not the one updated that only bounds to install High Sierra OS)
- Now install your default OS.
- After this, inside the default OS, go to app store and download the High Sierra installer and install from there. Installation seemed to go fine.

Loads of effort but at least does the trick,

Hope it helps.